# How to retain scroll position of a list in ionic on state change

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have a long list of items and on item click it will go to item description page i am using state.go() method to navigate. The problem is When I scroll down say some 30 or 50 elements and tap on item it will show that items description, when I press back button,the position of the list not retaining to previous position instead it is set to the top.

Comment: Did you ?: Retain Scroll Position On List Reload ? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/719

Comment: what about using Ionic 3?